# How to implement a sequence of forms

Tags: django, django-forms

New to Django here. I want to implement two forms in a sequence, where the second form depends on the saving of the first form. For example: View_A implements GET / POST methods of form A. Once Form A is submitted and saved, it will generate a unique ID. Form A also has a radio button with two choices (B and C). Depending on the choice made, I need to present the user with a second form B or a form C, where the unique ID from form A is filled automatically. The prerequisite for forms B and C is that the unique ID on form A is present. I can't use AJAX, because the form A needs to be saved first.

My problem is, as soon as I hit the submit button of form A, it becomes a POST request. I can generate the unique ID and display it in the returned html template. However, it's still the same view and I don't know how the display of next form. The display of form B/C should ideally be a GET request. But I am in the POST request.

I hope this is a clear enough question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement three views, one for each form. When the users saves form A, you check that the form is valid and generate the identifier. After that, just return a `HttpRedirect`. If the identifier is used for the process, you also give it as a parameter to the next view.

```
def my_view(request):
    # Construct your form from the POST data
    if form.is_valid():
        return redirect('next-form-view', identifier=your-generated-identifier)
```

Documentation about the redirect shortcut can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Comment: Cool Thanks. I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: If you specify what you use the identifier for I could give you advice on how to pass it around. Depending on your use case it could be advisable to save it in the database, pass it as a GET parameter or save it in the session. Passing it around in a hidden form field might have its use cases but I would not recommend it, as you would pass information around using the users browser.

Comment: The first form is an insurance claim creation form. Here the user inputs the initial info about the loss. The checkboxes B and C are IPhone and Android. The corresponding forms are supposed to collect the information about the device under loss. The identifier is the insurance claim ID. Once I have saved the claim on the first page, I need to collect the device information without losing the context and in the same flow.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: I was able to redirect the user to a new view and pass that claim ID on the top of the page using the method you mentioned. However, now, I am not able to pass that claim ID to the form B as one of the hidden field with a value attached to it. I solved it in a cludgy way. I sent the claim ID as a context field to the template and then used it in a hard coded hidden input field. <input type="hidden" name="claimId" value="{{currClaim.id}}">. When the user clicks the submit button, this input is now available in the kwargs of the post method of the form.